# Store line number of text file in table with bulk insert in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a text in the file like this :

```
In the name of God, the Mercy-giving, the Merciful! (1)
Praise be to God, Lord of the Universe, (2)
the Mercy-giving, the Merciful (3)
Ruler on the Day for Repayment! (4)
...
```

then, a table with 2 field like this :

```
TextData Varchar(max) NoNullable
Id       Int          NoNullable Identity(1,1)
```

When Use this query :

```
bulk insert MyDb.dbo.translation 
   FROM 'd:\IRVING.Arb' 
   WITH 
      ( 
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n', 
         codepage='1256' 
      )
```

I get **(0 row(s) affected)**

But, When I delete Id column from table , all line data copy it.

How can I store line number of file in Id columns ?

Comment: So the `(1), (2) etc.` line numbers are also in the text file, correct?

Comment: that sound like a bad idea. next time you want to load file they will have the same Id. what are you trying to do ? did you use log file to get the error ?

Comment: No, Line numbers no in text file. I want save in my table number of record data that set in TextData column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of this file is really specific and you have to specify a feature called "format file" so SQL Server knows the mapping of your file (what part of the file belongs to what sql column)

You could probably use something like this :

```
C:\test_format.fmt :

9.0
4
1       SQLCHAR       0       100      "("         1     Text 
2       SQLINT        0       12       ")\r\n"     2     Id
```

Add this to your bulk insert :

```
bulk insert MyDb.dbo.translation 
   FROM 'd:\IRVING.Arb' 
   WITH 
      ( 
         codepage='1256',
         FORMATFILE = 'C:\test_format.fmt'
      )
```

read more about format files here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

Comment: You say to me add line number to text file, then with format save these to my table ?

Comment: I thought lines were into your text already. If not, ignore my answer. I suggest you bulk insert into a staging/temporary table the raw data, then use a sql statement INSERT INTO so the identity works